# PKReveal Controller UIVIEW unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, slider

Ok I've tried REALLY hard to look through all the other posts about PKRevealController and figure this out... but it's just not happening so far. so here's what I've got:

AppDelegate.m

```
    ViewController *viewController = (ViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    UIViewController *leftViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    leftViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    PKRevealController *revealController = [PKRevealController revealControllerWithFrontViewController:viewController rightViewController:leftViewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = revealController;
```

My main view is just called ViewController. I just want to get the left swipe working. Maybe I'm just confused by what it's supposed to be doing... but it's giving me this error:

```
2015-02-06 14:02:40.810 bibi[5421:90b] (null)
2015-02-06 14:02:41.823 bibi[5421:90b] -[UIViewController setRevealController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcd7c9f0
2015-02-06 14:02:41.870 bibi[5421:90b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setRevealController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcd7c9f0'


    *** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02e181e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02b978e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02eb5243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02e0850b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02e080ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   bibi                                0x00007f55 -[PKRevealController initWithFrontViewController:leftViewController:rightViewController:options:] + 357
    6   bibi                                0x00007d59 -[PKRevealController initWithFrontViewController:rightViewController:options:] + 185
    7   bibi                                0x00007afc +[PKRevealController revealControllerWithFrontViewController:rightViewController:] + 188
    8   bibi                                0x0001fa61 -[AppDelegate redirect] + 321
    9   Foundation                          0x025c05ec __NSFireDelayedPerform + 372
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x02dd6ac6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x02dd64ad __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1181
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x02dbe538 __CFRunLoopRun + 1816
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x02dbd9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x02dbd7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x04de85ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x04de842b GSEventRun + 104
    17  UIKit                               0x0164af9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    18  bibi                                0x000eea3d main + 141
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x0335f725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I'm sure it's something simple and stupid that I'm just missing. But it's freezing and I have a cold and I'm just not getting it after trying and reading all the SO posts for two days...

**EDIT:** Added the complete log if that helps.

Comment: Add Expection Breakpoint for throw and catch as well and then run app again or follow the steps to crash and check where app gets crashed by exact line shown by break point.

Comment: Just look if your " leftViewController" or "viewController" need to implement any delegate..

Comment: @riyaz what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Just go to PKRevealController class file and search "delegate". You may see some method below "@protocol" (my suggestion was a guess though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  As it turns out there was absolutely nothing wrong with my code, and the solution to my problem was one that I haven't seen posted before so I'll post it here:

I installed PKRevealController using Cocoapods and the install didn't really complete successfully giving me the errors:

```
Debug is overwriting the Build Settings for "HEADER_LINK_PATH"
Debug is overwriting the Build Settings for "OTHER_LD_FLAGS"
```

I was load libsql and ObjC and a couple of other things in build settings but I wasn't inheriting the Pod settings for PKRevealController.

Deleting ObjC and using "$inherited" in those paths helped load PKRevealController and after that the program worked just fine. Just as a note to anyone who runs into this problem, you can load the settings you want (libsql in my case...) on one line AND $inherited on another line and they will work together just fine. Just remember to Clean your build and wipe the simulator (maybe even restart Xcode) and build again.